# How to call a method with a Nullable <T?>

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am creating a wrapper for API calls.  Here's the return object:

```
public class ApiCallResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string ErrorReason { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}

public class ApiCallResponse<T> : ApiCallResponse
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

`Data` is added as an option because it's possible (with a POST, for example) that we won't expect anything back in return other than a Status Code.

Then, I have this method:

```
private ApiCallResponse<T?> Call<T>(ApiCallInput input) where T : struct
{
   // do stuff and make the api call
}
```

That seems ok, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to call this method.

This:

```
public ApiCallResponse<T> CallExternalAPI<T>(ApiCallInput input)
{
    return Call<T>(input);
}
```

Gets me this:

> The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ApiCall.Call(ApiCallInput)'

And this:

```
public ApiCallResponse CallExternalAPI(ApiCallInput input)
{
    return Call(input);
}
```

Gets me this:

> The type arguments for method 'ApiCall.Call(ApiCallInput)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: You should specify the exact type of `T` when use the generic method, `Call<double>(new ApiCallInput());` works fine. The result will be `ApiCallResponse<double?>`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski But doesn't that defeats the entire point of the generic T? The exact type isn't known until runtime.

Comment: `T` is constrained for `Call<T>` to `where T : struct`. So this constraint must also be applied to `CallExternalApi<T>`.

Comment: If the exact type is not known until runtime, then providing compile-time type checks (which is what generics do) is not useful.

Comment: @theMayer, ok... so I should not be using  `where T : struct`? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Not necessarily. Your description of the problem is not clear enough to provide guidance on implementation. If defining an API, what is the nature of the code that will be calling it?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston without the constraint, you could not use `T?` at all, because only value types can be generic arguments of `Nullable<X>`.

Comment: I can offer that it would be unusual for an API call to return a struct. Typically, structs are only used when the specific behavioral properties and uses of structs are needed. Otherwise, objects (which are always nullable references) are preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You constrained `T` to be a value type for `Call<T>`

```
private ApiCallResponse<T?> Call<T>(ApiCallInput input) where T : struct
```

So you need to also contrain `T` in `CallExternalAPI<T>`:

```
public ApiCallResponse<T> CallExternalAPI<T>(ApiCallInput input) where T : struct
```

The compiler needs to be sure that the `T` of `CallExternalAPI` can be used as generic argument for `Call`.

---

But then you still have the problem that a `ApiCallResponse<T?>` is not assignable to a `ApiCallResponse<T>`. Maybe it's a typo, but `CallExternalAPI<T>` should be declared to also return a `ApiCallResponse<T?>`.

Comment: This solved `return Call<T>(input);` but not `return Call(input);`

Comment: @CaseyCrookston of course not, you did not declare a **non**-generic `Call` method, so what do you expect the compiler to call for `Call(input);`? `void` is not a generic argument.

Comment: So do I need an overload method such as `private ApiCallResponse Call(ApiCallInput input)`

Comment: @CaseyCrookston yes, that's one possibility.

Comment: :) How would you handle it?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Just like that. I'd implement a non-generic `Call` method that returns an instance of the non-generic `ApiCallResponse` class.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the same generic constraint on `CallExternalAPI<T>` method, and use the same `ApiCallResponse<T?>` declaration

```cs
public ApiCallResponse<T?> CallExternalAPI<T>(ApiCallInput input) where T : struct
{
    return Call<T>(input);
}
```

Or specify the generic type parameter, like

```cs
var result = Call<double>(new ApiCallInput());
```

the result will have `ApiCallResponse<double?>` type.

---

This code will never compile

```cs
public ApiCallResponse CallExternalAPI(ApiCallInput input)
{
    return Call(input);
}
```

The error message tells you an exact problem

> Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

You should specify the generic type argument, something like pointed above

Comment: I can't use anything like `var result = Call<double>(new ApiCallInput());` because I have no idea what the actual Type will be. Hard coding it will entirely defeat the purpose here.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Then you should declare `ApiCallResponse<T?>` properly, as nullable. and restrict it to `struct` as well. Second sample won't work, since you can't call a generic method with generic parameters